# React state material ui map conflict on update

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, react-state, array.prototype.map

I am having a problem with React state changes accros two different components

The Parent Class has the state of the commands and the functions that change the state

```
constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            expanded: false,
            addLock: false,
            pendingCommand: undefined,
            commands: [],
            defCommands: [],
        };

render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <this.Commands/>
            </div>
        );
    }
```

The two different components are Material ui Custom Accordions in tabs

```
Commands = () => {

   const tabs = [
   <CommandAccordion
       cmd={this.state.defcommands}
       expan={this.state.expanded} addLock={this.state.addLock}
       hdlICh={this.handleInputChange}/>,
   <CommandAccordion
       cmd={this.state.commands} pendCmd={this.state.pendingCommand}
       expan={this.state.expanded} addLock={this.state.addLock}
       hdlICh={this.handleInputChange}/>]
}
```

The Accordion maps through the commands like this:

```
const commands = props.cmd;
const pendingCommand = props.pendCmd;

{[...pendingCommand === undefined ? [] : [pendingCommand], ...commands].map((obj, index) => (
<CstmAccordion expanded={expanded === obj._id} onChange={handleChange(obj._id, index)}
                           onClick={() => customOnChange(obj)}
                           key={'accordion-defcommands-' + index}>
    <CstmAccordionDetails>
           <Tabs value={tabId}>
                <StyledTab label="Settings"/>
                <StyledTab label="Advanced settings"/>
           </Tabs>
<TabPanel value={tabId} Id={0} index={index} obj={obj} funcs={funcs}
     commandV={commandValue}/>
<TabPanel value={tabId} Id={1} index={index} obj={obj} funcs={funcs}
     commandV={commandValue}/>
```

Now the tab pannel has its own state which is set at the beginning and is used in a text field as value

```
const [commandValue, setCommandValue] = React.useState(obj.command);

<TextField
      value={commandValue}
      onBlur={funcs.handleInputChange(index, 'command')}
      onSelect={() => {
          funcs.handleOnFieldSelect(index)
      }}
      helperText={`What triggers the response? ${!commandValue ? 0 : commandNameValue.length}/40`}
      onChange={(event) => {
         if (event.target.value.length <= 40)
            setCommandValue(event.target.value);
         }}/>
```

Now the problem is if I first load everything it opens the tab for the default command in the parent component and everything looks fine. But if I change the tab to the custom commands, **the first command in the Custom-Command-Tab has the same value like the first command in the Default-Command-Tab.** *(With Tabs I mean `const tabs =[...` in `Commands = () =>{` and not `<TabPanel .../>`)*

And if I change the value in the custom command, save it and change back to the default tab now the default commands have the value of the custom commands.

Also it might be important to now that value only syncs with the other commands with the same index. Which means the second command in the second tab has its own value and not the same value like the command before it - but is still synced with the second command in the first tab.

I think it might have something to do with the order in which the comopnents are rendered but I dont konw.

I've tried managing the state in the Accordion bevore the `commands.map` function and not in the TabPanel, and changing the state everytime the Accordion is clicked, and giving the TabPanel the `commandValue` and `SetCommandValue` and this works in terms of the sync problem, but with that the input into the TextField and has a 2 second input delay per char at worst.

I hope you can understand my problem even if it's a bit much.